# java.lang.FileNotFoundException in Android/Kotlin even though file is present

Tags: android, json, kotlin, filenotfoundexception

I have a data class called Contact which has a companion object property 'allContacts: List' which returns contacts after parsing them from a JSON file.

Relevant code:

```kotlin
val allContacts: List<Contact>
            get() {
                val json = JSONObject(File("app/src/main/res/data/contacts.json").readText()).getJSONArray("contacts")
                val contacts = mutableListOf<Contact>()
                ...
```

I do indeed have a contacts.json in res/data package. (data package created manually).

Here's the proof:

[image]

Why is this happening? Is the contacts.json file not included in the final .apk?

I have tried logging the current path of the app using

```kotlin
Log.i('.MainActivity', System.getProperty('user.dir'))
```

But always get `.` in Logcat.

EDIT: I decompiled the apk in Android Studio and found no traces of contacts.json

Comment: The working directory of your app is not your project folder. You cannot access your file as file. In a desktop app I would access it by getResourceAsStream() but I don't know if there is a better way on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file doesn't exist in the same project directory you expect it to.
You have to create a resource directory `raw` and paste your file in there.
Then, you can reference your file as `R.raw.contacts` wherever you need  to reference the file.

Reading the file is another story.

I found it best to create a separate top-level extension function for reading and returning the file contents

```kotlin
fun Activity.readFile(fileID: Int): String {
 val inputStream = this.resources.openRawResources(fileID)
 return inputStream.use{it.readText()} // Returns entirety of file contents as string.
}
```